# Finding Matching Strings Within Paragraphs

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I have a TXT file with LaTeX math equations where a single $ delimiter is used before and after each inline equation.

I would like to find each of the equations within a paragraph and replace the delimiters with XML opening and closing tags ....

E.g.,

The following paragraph:

```
This is the beginning of a paragraph $first equation$ ...and here is some text... $second equation$ ...and here is more text... $third equation$ ...and here is yet more text... $fourth equation$
```

should become:

```
This is the beginning of a paragraph <equation>first equation</equation> ...and here is some text... <equation>second equation</equation> ...and here is more text... <equation>third equation</equation> ...and here is yet more text... <equation>fourth equation</equation>
```

I have tried the sed and perl commands such as the following:

```
perl -p -e 's/(\$)(.*[^\$])(\$)/<equation>$2<\/equation>/'
```

But these commands result in the first and last instances of equations being converted but none of the equations between these two:

```
This is the beginning of a paragraph <equation>first equation$ ...and here is some text... $second equation$ ...and here is more text... $third equation$ ...and here is yet more text... $fourth equation</equation>
```

I also would like a robust solution that could take into account the presence of a single $ that is not used as a LaTeX delimiter. E.g.,

```
This is the beginning of a paragraph $first equation$ ...and here is some text that includes a single dollar sign: He paid $2.50 for a pack of cigarettes... $second equation$ ...and here is more text... $third equation$ ...and here is yet more text... $fourth equation$
```

does not become:

```
This is the beginning of a paragraph <equation>first equation$ ...and here is some text that includes a single dollar sign: He paid <equation>2.50 for a pack of cigarettes... $second equation$ ...and here is more text... $third equation$ ...and here is yet more text... $fourth equation</equation>
```

Note: I am writing in Bash.

Comment: I am not familiar with LaTeX, but I guess there are no spaces inside the formulae, right?

Comment: @PedroMaimere There can be spaces within the `$...$` of a LaTeX math expression.

Comment: Is there anything that can trigger whether the dollar signs (don't) belong to a formula?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not that I can think of. There sometimes are LaTeX commands (e.g., \frac) immediately after the first $ but not always. There are sometimes just numbers or parentheses or text and all these may be found after a $ that is used for a different purpose...What distinguishes the LaTeX equations from other uses of $ is that the equations are always enclosed within a $ whereas a single $ could be used for another purpose. It is hard to rule out false positives in this case.

Comment: cursory search for (la)tex, dollar signs, equations ... found a couple references perhaps OP can comment on: **1)** use `\(...\)` instead of `$...$` to designate equations, **2)** escape the standalone `$` (ie, `\$`) to designate it as a literal `$`; are either of these (realistic) options that could be used to assist with determining how a `$` should be processed?

Comment: I am exporting a DOCX to Markdown using Pandoc and the inline LaTEX always has the `$...$` delimiters. I am aware of `\(...\)` but do not know of a Pandoc filter that can be used to render the equations in that way. Yes, we can escape the standalone `$`, which when exported to Markdown will appear as `\\\$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE**: First part of this answer focuses solely on replacing pairs of `$'s`; for OP's request to **not** replace standalone `$'s` ... see 2nd half of answer.

---

**Replacing pairs of `$'s`**

Sample data:

```
$ cat latex.txt
... $first equation$ ... $second equation$ ... $third equation$
```

One `sed` idea:

```
sed -E 's|\$([^$]*)\$|<equation>\1</equation>|g' latex.txt
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support
- `\$` - match a literal `$`
- `([^$]*)` - [capture group #1] - match everything that is not a literal `$` (in this case everything between the pair of `$'s`)
- `\$`  - match a literal `$`
- `<equation>\1</equation>` - replace the matched string with `<equation>` + `contents of capture group` + `</equation>`
- `/g` - repeat search/replace as often as necessary

This generates:

```
... <equation>first equation</equation> ... <equation>second equation</equation> ... <equation>third equation</equation>
```

---

**Dealing with standalone `$`**

If the standalone `$` can be escaped (eg, `\$`) one idea would be to have `sed` replace this with a nonsensical literal, perform the `<equation> / </equation>` replacement, then change the nonsensical literal back to `\$`.

Sample data:

```
$ cat latex.txt
... $first equation$ ... $second equation$ ... $third equation$
... $first equation$ ... \$3.50 cup of coffee ... $third equation$
```

Original `sed` solution with the new replacements:

```
sed -E 's|\\\$|LITDOL|g;s|\$([^$]*)\$|<equation>\1</equation>|g;s|LITDOL|\\\$|g' latex.txt
```

Where we replace `\$` with `LITDOL` (LITeral DOLlar), perform our original replacment, then switch `LITDOL` back to `\$`.

Which generates:

```
... <equation>first equation</equation> ... <equation>second equation</equation> ... <equation>third equation</equation>
... <equation>first equation</equation> ... \$3.50 cup of coffee ... <equation>third equation</equation>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to plug the line of code into my script and it is working fine. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: With sed the normal "thing that can't exist in the input" is `\n` so you could use that instead of `LITDOL` so you don't have to worry about it being present in  the input.

Answer (score 3):

Try this Perl using negative lookahead.

```
$ cat joseph.txt
This is the beginning of a paragraph $first equation$ ...and here is some text that includes a single dollar sign: He paid $2.50 for a pack of cigarettes... $second equation$ ...and here is more text... $third equation$ ...and here is yet more text... $fourth equation$
$ perl -p -e 's/(\$)(?![\d.]+)(.+?)(\$)/<equation>$2<\/equation>/g' joseph.txt
This is the beginning of a paragraph <equation>first equation</equation> ...and here is some text that includes a single dollar sign: He paid $2.50 for a pack of cigarettes... <equation>second equation</equation> ...and here is more text... <equation>third equation</equation> ...and here is yet more text... <equation>fourth equation</equation>
$
```

Comment: This is also LaTeX equation `$2+a$` what would be happened in the above code?

Comment: ````(?![\d.]+)\s```` an extra space would work

Comment: space doesn't matter in the equations might be `$ 2 + A + B $`,  `$2AB$`
I am not familiar with LaTeX Just a clarification may be OP got success in your answer well and good.

Comment: @ssr1012.. yes right... this is tricky!.. not sure how LateX is described.